# ASP.Net WebApi Key Vault configBuilders fail to process

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I am setting up an Azure Key Vault configuration in a web app using .net framework 4.8. I used the following guide to set up a connected service to pull secrets from key vault: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service)

When running the setup locally I get the yellow error screen with the following error.
[image]

Also seeing some exceptions thrown in the debug window.

[image]

Setup of configBuilders below:
[image]

Comment: Do you have access / permissions to this key vault ? Also did you configure visual studio : `options -> azure app authentication` ?

Comment: did you check the troubleshooting section of the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service#troubleshooting ?

Comment: @Thomas yes, we set up an access policy using a group that I am a part of and it should have full control of the key vault. Also looked in the tools menu you mentioned and my account is configured there.

Comment: When you say, I should have access: would you be able to check from the azure portal the permissions you have on KV please ?

Comment: Also if you could manage to get the underlying error, iut will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Added some exceptions from the debug window to the question. Looks like its having trouble loading the configurationBuilders dll. Tried uninstalling and re-installing the nugets but no luck. Also have tried running as admin but same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me know if the answer helped

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service) but wasn't able to create a connected service from Visual Studio 2022 for an ASP.NET 4.8 MVC.

There is an interesting note at the end of this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002040#added-references-for-aspnet-framework):

> By default Azure.Identity 1.1.1 is installed, which does not support Visual Studio Credential. You can update package reference manually to 1.2+ use Visual Studio Credential.

Anyway I found this great [article](https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-retrieve-connection-strings-in-azure-key-vault-from-asp-net-using-configuration-builders-xml-transformation-and-azure-devops/) that explains how to configure it manually.

1. Added reference to these nuget packages: `Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure (2.0.0), Azure.Identity(1.6.0), Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets(4.3.0)`.
   I had to manually update to latest version.
2. Make sure the `configSections` and `configBuilders` are properly set:

   ```
   <configSections>
     <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
   </configSections>
   <configBuilders>
     <builders>
     <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="[vaultName]" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /></builders>
   </configBuilders>
   ```
3. The `appSettings` needs to be configured to use the builder:

   ```
   <appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
   ```

Then it worked for me. As described in the previous link, it is probably related to incompatible nuget packages pr just versions.

Comment: This got past the error in the question so thank you for that! It looks like app settings are still not populating with the secret values. I can see some errors again in the debug window that seem to point to an identity issue. Exception thrown: 'Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException' in mscorlib.dll
It should just be using the user under tools -> Azure Service Authentication right?

Comment: Yeah make sure the credentials haven't expired and that the user has read / list secret permission on key vault.